# Условие if java

Tags: java

Наверное, я чего-то не понимаю. Есть поле для ввода и кнопка. Делаю условие: если содержимое поля `== 1` то... Но, что бы я не вводил, условие не выполняется.

```
     View.OnClickListener editSettings = new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (oldPass.getText().toString() == "1" ) {
                    Toast.makeText(Settings.this, "ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Settings.this, "Старый пароль указан неверно" + oldPass.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        };

        editSet.setOnClickListener(editSettings);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не сравнивайте объекты, используя `==`, ибо этот оператор сравнивает ссылки на строки, а не сами строки.

Для сравнения объектов используется `.equals()`:

```
String s1 = "string";
String s2 = "string";

System.out.println(s1.equals(s2)); // true
```

В вашем случае:

```
oldPass.getText().toString().equals("1")
```

Обратное условие:

```
!oldPass.getText().toString().equals("1")
```

Comment: А не равняется тогда как?

Comment: @NDA дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Для правильного условия оператора используй

```
if(oldPass.getText().toString().equals("1")){...}else{...}...
```

Answer (score -1):

попробуй так:

```
if (oldPass.equals( "1") ) {
```